# Безопасность в архитектуре микросервисов

Tags: безопасность, архитектура, ddd, микросервисы

**Ситуация:**

Есть система, подразделяющаяся на следующие контексты (используются стратегические шаблоны DDD):

1. контекст идентификации и доступа (идентификация и авторизация)
2. контекст регистрации определенных объектов
3. контекст опроса (для получения информации о зарегистрированных объектах)

Исходя из указанного разделения задач я принял решение строить систему на основе архитектуры микросервисов.

**Задача:**

Обеспечение безопасности системы

**Вопрос:**

Исходя из представленных выше контекстов возникает вопрос относительно поддержания безопасности такой системы. В данном случае получается, что идентификация и авторизация всех сервисов расположена в одном узле. С моей точки зрения:

1. это не безопасно - выход из строя данного узла обрушит безопасность всей системы;
2. микросервисы становятся менее автономными;

У кого есть опыт построения микросервисной архитектуры, подскажите, пожалуйста: как в таком случае лучше обеспечивать безопасность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала можно ознакомиться с хорошей вводной статьёй из четырёх частей:

- https://auth0.com/blog/an-introduction-to-microservices-part-1/
- https://auth0.com/blog/an-introduction-to-microservices-part-2-API-gateway/
- https://auth0.com/blog/an-introduction-to-microservices-part-3-the-service-registry/
- https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices-part-4-dependencies/

Плюс, почитать про двенадцатифакторные приложения:

- https://12factor.net/ru/

Рекомендую также "Чистую архитектуру" Роберта Мартина, а именно главу 27, где автор пишет, что по-возможности вопрос о микросерверной организации кода надо откладывать на потом. Мода на микросервисы пройдёт, а код может остаться, поэтому так.

Что касается вашего конкретного вопроса. Ваши микросервисы вы прячете за так называемый *шлюз* (gateway), который выполняет функции авторизации, балансировки нагрузки, и увязывания микросервисов. Часто структуру решения организуют так, чтобы один шлюз соответствовал одному клиентскому приложению — для веб-клиента один, для мобильного клиента другой.

Итак, вы разрабатываете шлюз — по сути такой же микросервис — который доступен снаружи и прячете за него два микросервиса с бизнес-логикой. Сервис аутентификации ставите отдельно. Можете использовать внешние сервисы, например, Google или Facebook, которые умеют аутентифицировать пользователей по OAuth2. Для .NET существует полуфабричное решение IdentityServer.

Если боитесь за надёжность, можете за балансировщиком спрятать два-три-четыре копии аутентификатора. Если боитесь, что датацентр выйдет из строя, ставьте в разных датацентрах балансировщики с аутентификаторами, и распределяйтесь запросы через Round robin DNS. Практически, это уже лишнее — такие решения нужны, когда речь идёт о крупных состоявшихся проектах.

Аутентификатор будет отдавать вам `access_token`, наверное, в стандарте JWT. Шлюз, обрабатывая заголовки HTTP-запроса, будет извлекать этот токен из заголовка **Authorization**, проверять подпись и брать оттуда идентификатор пользователя.

Внутрь микросервисам передаётся уже идентификатор пользователя. Считается, что пользователь корректный, потому что подпись подделать статистически невероятно.

Схема с токенами доступа (access token) и обновления (refresh token) хорошо себя зарекомендовала, описана в стандарте OAuth2, и поддержана инструментально. Скажем, тот же IdentityServer может отдавать готовые токены.

Comment: Марк, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Однако не совсем понятно: как быть в случае наличия ролей? Например, пользователь зарегистрирован, но не подтвержден. В таком случае я не могу предоставить пользователю доступ к сервисам контекста платных услуг. Роль "Покупатель" будет присвоена пользователю только при подтверждении пользователя.
Кроме того, микросервис авторизации будет иметь список ролей и доступных для них действий для всех микросервисов. Не слишком ли много будет знать такой сервис о другим и не слишком ли большая ответственность возлагается на этот узел?

Comment: @Eladei, это сервис *аутентификации*, не *авторизации*. Он проверяет логин/пароль и возвращает вам *идентификатор пользователя*. Права пользователя относятся уже к микросервисам, и сами микросервисы должны проверять, может ли пользователь делать что-либо или нет. Про пользователя кроме идентификатора они ничего не знают. Если сервис аутентификации отдаёт вам идентификатор, значит, пользователь уже подтверждён. Вы можете для всех новых пользователей назначать роль *Покупатель*, то есть назначать её, если у пользователя нет никакой роли.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю принцип:
1) User регистрируется при помощи сервиса аутентификации (СА)
2) СА публикует событие "User Registered"
3) User подтверждает свой email
4) СА публикует событие "User Confirmed"
5) Сервис платных услуг (СПУ) получает данное событие, периодически проверяя СА, регистрирует у себя Покупателя (Customer) с ID User'а и присваивает ему роль "Customer"
6) Пользователь вводит логин и пароль и получает необходимые токены (доступа и обновления). Токены СА получает от сервиса генерации токенов (СГТ).
7) СПУ обращается к СГТ для его проверки и проверяет роль.

Comment: @Eladei, там в начале никаких событий. Пользователь регистрируется, получает письмо, подтверждает себя, после этого логинится, получает `access_token` и с ним лезет в gateway (шлюз). Шлюз умеет проверить, что токен корректный, не со стороны, и если он корректный, то шлюз достаёт оттуда `userId` и уже запрос с этим `userId` отправляет в микросервис. Микросервис лезет в базу, если там такого `userId` нет, значит, пользователь новый, надо его зарегистрировать и назначить ему роль *Покупатель*. Если пользователь есть, то смотрим его роль, и его запрос, и разрешаем или запрещаем.

Comment: Марк, большое Вам спасибо за ответы. Буду продолжать смотреть в данном направлении.

Comment: @Eladei Полистайте первую статью по ссылкам (4 части), они мне в своё время здорово помогли.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Именно с них я и хотел начать)